# How to compute the value of $1 \cdot \frac{2}3 \cdot \frac 45 \cdots$, as $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It's supposed to be $\dfrac 12\sqrt{\dfrac \pi n}$.

Comment: did you try Stirling's approximation?

Comment: You can't really have $n$ in the limiting value...

Comment: Is this $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{2n+1}$?

Comment: By the way, titles are for titles; the body is supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: See [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question is also confusing because the title implies he is looking for a limit, but the body's suggested answer is for an asymptotic expression for the finite products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wallis's product in the following form ( [*Advanced Calculus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471025666) by Angus Taylor, formula (20.7-9))

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\pi }{2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \frac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}{
1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)}\right) ^{2}\frac{1}{2n+1}\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

follows that the limit in the title is zero.

ADDED. The formula $(1)$ is a consequence of the following double inequality
\begin{equation*}
\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{\pi }{2}<\left( \frac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}{1\cdot
3\cdots (2n-1)}\right) ^{2}\frac{1}{2n+1}<\frac{\pi }{2},\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

which can be derived integrating over the interval $]0,\pi/2[$

$$\sin^{2n+1}\theta<\sin^{2n}\theta<\sin^{2n-1}\theta.\tag{3}$$

Inequality $(2)$ can be rewritten as

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n+1}\sqrt{\pi }<\frac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}{1\cdot 3\cdots
(2n-1)\left( 2n+1\right) }<\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2\left( 2n+1\right) }}<\frac{1}{
2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{n}},\tag{4}
\end{equation*}

thus proving the asymptotic expression you indicate in the question body. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I want, good to know the Wallis's product. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user129542 Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
$$
1\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{2^{2n+1} n!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!}
$$
Now we use Stirling's asymptotic approximation
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^n}=1,
$$
and obtain
$$
\frac{2^{2n+1} n!(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!}=\frac{\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^n}
\cdot\frac{(n+1)!}{\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n+1}}}{\frac{(2n+2)!}{\sqrt{2\pi (2n+2)}\left(\frac{2n+2}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{2n+2}}}\cdot
\frac{2^{2n+1}\sqrt{2\pi (2n+2)}\left(\frac{2n+2}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{2n+2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^n\cdot\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n+1}}.
$$
The first factor of the right-hand side tends to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\half\,{2 \over 3}\,{4 \over 5}\cdots{2n \over 2n + 1}
=
{\pars{1.2.4\ldots 2n}^{2}/4 \over 2.3.4.5\ldots\pars{2n}\pars{2 n + 1}}
={1 \over 4}\,{\pars{2\ n!}^{2} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}
$$

> When $n \gg 1$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\half\,{2 \over 3}\,{4 \over 5}\cdots{2n \over 2n + 1}
> \sim{\pars{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}^{2}
>   \over \root{2\pi}\pars{2n + 1}^{2n + 3/2}\expo{-\pars{2n + 1}}}
> ={{\rm e} \over \root{2\pi}}\,{n^{2n + 1} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2n + 3/2}}
> \\[3mm]&={{\rm e} \over \root{2\pi}}\,{1 \over 2^{2n + 1}\root{2n + 1}}\,
> \pars{1 + {1 \over 2n}}^{-2n - 1}
> \\[3mm]&\sim{{\rm e} \over \root{2\pi}}\,{1 \over 2^{2n + 1}\root{2n + 1}}\,
> \exp\pars{-\bracks{2n + 1}\,{1 \over 2n}}
> \sim{1 \over \root{2\pi}}\,{1 \over 2^{2n + 1}\root{2n + 1}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\half\,{2 \over 3}\,{4 \over 5}\cdots{2n \over 2n + 1}}}
=\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{{1 \over \root{2\pi}}\,{1 \over 2^{2n + 1}\root{2n + 1}}}
=\color{#00f}{\large 0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try this transformation:
$$ R_n = \frac{1\cdot2\cdot4\cdots(2n)}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n+1)} = \frac{(1\cdot2\cdot4\cdots(2n))^2}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdots(2n)(2n+1)} = \frac{(2^n n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$
and then use Sterling approximation to expand the factorials.